# Simulate random variable with PDF $x^2+\frac4 3x$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

Consider $X$ a random variable with the following density function:

$f(x) =$\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{x ∉ [0,1]} \\
x^2+\frac4 3*x, & \text{x  \in [0,1]}
\end{cases}

I need to write a function in Matlab that simulates $X$ using envelope method(simulation)(not sure if this is how it's called in english).
We consider

$h(x) =$\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{x ∉ [0,1]} \\
1, & \text{x ∈ [0,1]}
\end{cases}

Could use some help! Thank you!

EDIT:

In one of my courses it says to look for a variable $a$ so
$f(x) \leq a*h(x)$.
Then

```
do
 {
   simulate u random variable of U ~ U(0,1)
   simulate y random variable of Y with density h(y)
 }
while(u<=f(x)/a*h(y))
```

$x=y$

$x$ random variable of $X$ with density function $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is a method which samples $(x,y)$ uniformly from the square $[0,1] \times [0,M]$, then returns $y$ if $y \leq x^2 + \frac{4}{3} x$, or else tries again (rejecting the point). Here $M$ is such that $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x$. In this case the smallest such $M$ is $f(1)=\frac{7}{3}$.

There's not a whole lot to be said here in terms of MATLAB implementation: you need a loop (to repeat trials), you need the function rand (to get values of (x,y)), and you need comparison. You also need a way to get out of the loop when you're done (I can think of three different ways to do that). That's all.